# How to store CGPoint in CGRect

Tags: iphone, ios

I placed an UIImageView,on the imageView UIView is placed.If I touch on that view some which i touched have to be removed at that time we will see the some part of image(this is my requirement).So please tell me in which way i will do 
                 Thanks in advance

Comment: Point and rectangle are different things. What is the meaning of converting a point to a rectangle? You need to explain more what you want.

Comment: I want to store the touch points.depends on that i have to make a frame to another view,If i touch on the same view then the frame of the another view have to be changed

Comment: @SivaNagendra really don't think that your question could be answered. Please show us what did you tried, or explain more by editing your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood from your hints above, You may use NSValue to store CGPoint and CGRect in collection. Check out the link below, you may get idea or may be that could be helpful.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/storing-cgpoint-cgsize-and-cgrect-in-collections-with-nsvalue.html